# does android creates an object of the activity class to run its lifecycle methods

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            //handle multiple view click events
        }
    }
}
```

```
Button myFirstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_FIRST_BUTTON);
myFirstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

my question is since we are using object of activitymain class here when using this in setonclicklistener ,how does android run a activity?

does it run its lifecycle methods directly from an activity class ?
also how does object of activitymain comes into picture in android?